# Class \"Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Middleware\\BaseMiddleware\" not found in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, jwt, tymon-jwt

In laravel 9 I am using tymon\jwt-auth package.
In composer.json`"tymon/jwt-auth": "2.x",`

In config/app.php in providers array i added

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
```

and aliases

```
'JWTAuth'=>Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class,  
'JWTFactory' =>Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class,
```

app\Http\Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
   ];
```

config\auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
]
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

I am writing my own middleware named as Customer.php and importing this

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\BaseMiddleware;
```

in my middleware, but the above class is not found. I replaced the use statement as

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate;
```

But this class is depricated.

[image: All classes in Http\Middleware are depricated]

Kindly help how can I get rid of this error. I have spent three days but no progress yet. All the classes in Http\Middleware are deprecated.

Comment: Did you reinstall the package?

Comment: yes many times-----------

Comment: I checked in their official github, there are those Middleware class.

Answer (score 1):

The classes are marked as deprecated in the repository and the maintainer likely has a reason to mark them as such. I have not found any hints about this middleware in the documentation either.

I suggest using [the documented authorization method](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/auth-guard/#validate) in a custom middleware without relying on the BaseMiddleware:

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
 
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
 
class EnsureUserIsAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if (! auth()->validate($credentials)) {
            // credentials are invalid, redirect user to login?
        }
 
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and then use that middleware on your routes with the standard middleware configuration in the Kernel.php

```php
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    'jwt-authenticated' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureUserIsAuthenticated::class,
];
```